# Removing background gradient from scanned image

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for a good way to do batch-image processing of various scanned images. The images are quite large (300dpi at a4), but image processing time should not be a concern.

The general problem is this: The image may be colored but doesn't necessarily have to be, some of them are black and white. They have the quite typical fold-mark in the middle that comes from scanning books. What I would like to have is an image cleaned of that fold mark, which looks like a gradient, and (as an added bonus) color-shifted so that the actual background appears white / light gray. An example image is this (source is Haeckel's [Kunstformen der Natur](http://caliban.mpipz.mpg.de/haeckel/kunstformen/index.html), for anyone interested):

[image: Scanned Example]

I pondered on doing it in Python with an adaptive contrast filter, but didn't really come up with good solution yet; pretty much any input for any framework / tool / language could help me.

Comment: Can you add some annotated example as i don't understand what you want to remove. **edit** Okay i think i see it. The left part of the inner-construct is darker than the right one.

Comment: The whole background is not uniformly colored. It gets darker on the edges; ideally it would be closer to having a solid color while preserving the fine details (see the writing and drawings).

Comment: Your example doesn't have the fold mark, do you have one of those too?

Comment: The fold mark doesn't get much stronger than this. You don't actually *see* the fold, but you see that the scan is not completely straight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick hack using [vips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS). It does a huge blur (gaussian with sigma 200) to get the background, then scales up the image by the amount it's dark by.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import gi
gi.require_version('Vips', '8.0')
from gi.repository import Vips

image = Vips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])

# huge gaussian blur to remove all high frequences ... we will just be left with
# the changes in the background
smooth = image.gaussblur(200)

# scale up the darker areas of the original ... we scale up by the proportion they
# are darker than white by
image *= smooth.max() / smooth

# that'll make rather a dazzling white ... knock it back a bit
image *= 0.9

image.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

Run like this:

```
$ time ./remove_gradient.py ~/Desktop/orig.jpg x.jpg
real    0m16.369s
user    0m55.704s
sys 0m0.218s
```

There's still some vignetting, but it seems reduced, to me.

[image: after scale by blur]